# Problems creating an action for every object in an array

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, arrays, afnetworking

I have run into a strange situation when creating trying to save the objects from an array to a rails backend. I have two array and I have no problem saving each one on its own. The problem is that I am also creating a table that is a combination of the two objects. So it would be best to create an action for index path 1 for both arrays, index path 2 for both arrays and so on. The arrays will always have the same amount of objects inside of them. This way, for index path one, it could save both of them and make the combination table at the same time, thus eliminating my problem. My second problem is that I have no idea how to create a block of code that executes for an index path of multiple array. I know this is probably quite weird, but any help would be great.

Here is how I was doing it for every object of a **single** array:

```
-(void)savePeroid {

    [self.periodArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor == [UIColor redColor]) {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/"];
            AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

            NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    object, @"period[name]",
                                    nil];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                    path:@"api/period"
                                                              parameters:params];
            AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

                NSLog(@"ID: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"id"]);
            } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                NSLog(@"Request Failure Because %@",[error userInfo]);
            }];

            [operation start];
        }
    }];

    [self saveSubject];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
-(void)savePeroid {

for (int i=0; i<self.periodArray.count; i++) {
    id periodObject = self.periodArray[i];
    id otherArrayObject = self.otherArray[i];

    if (self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor == [UIColor redColor]) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/"];
        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

        NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                periodObject, @"period[name]",
                                otherArrayObject, @"other[something]",
                                nil];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                path:@"api/period"
                                                          parameters:params];
        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

            NSLog(@"ID: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"id"]);
        } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
            NSLog(@"Request Failure Because %@",[error userInfo]);
        }];

        [operation start];
    }
};

[self saveSubject];
}
```

Comment: Hey, one question. Because there is another action that should happen only if both objects at a certain index path save, is there a way to stop it going on to the next index if one comes back with a failure. Also, would you have any advice for making one piece of code only run after both objects at an index path come back a success, but before it moves on to the next index path. My goal is to save the object in both arrays and then make a connection between the two, then move on to the next index path